# Pullback of a connection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, connections

let $X,Y$ be smooth schemes (or rigid spaces etc..) over a base $S$, let $f:Y \rightarrow X$ be a $S$-morphisn and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module with connection $\nabla$. How do we define the "pull-back connection" along $f$? We get a connection $$f^{-1}\mathcal{F} \overset{f^{-1}\nabla}{\rightarrow} f^{-1}\mathcal{F}  \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X} f^{-1} \Omega^1_X,$$ do we extend this to $f^{\ast}\mathcal{F}$ by taking $f^{\ast}\nabla= f^{-1}\nabla \otimes  d_Y : f^{-1}\mathcal{F}  \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_Y$ (as tensor product of connections) or how?

Sorry for the stupid question but it is hard to find references on connections which are not written in the language of differential geometry.

Comment: Take a look at a book on D-modules.

Comment: Let $\Delta \hookrightarrow X\times X$ be the diagonal,  $\Delta '$ its first infinitesimal neighborhood (defined by $\mathscr{I}_{\Delta }^2$), $p_1,p_2$ the two projections from $\Delta '$ to $X$. You can view a connection on a vector bundle $E$ as an isomorphism 
$p_1^*E\rightarrow p_2^*E$ on $\Delta '$ inducing the identity on $\Delta $. 
Then you just have to pull back this isomorphism by the morphism $\Delta '_Y\rightarrow \Delta '_X$ induced by $f$.

Comment: Thank you both, I am aware of both notions (D-modules and stratifications) but I am looking for an explicit statement in terms of connections. Shouldn't there be a simple answer here?

Comment: @user2520938 the connection is not assumed to be integrable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that you have a map $f^* \colon f^{-1} \Omega_X \to \Omega_Y$ (pull-back of differentials). Consider the composition $$ \nabla' \colon f^{-1} E \xrightarrow{f^{-1} \nabla} f^{-1} E\otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_X} f^{-1}\Omega_X \xrightarrow{{\rm id}\otimes f^*} f^{-1} E\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X} \Omega_Y = f^* E \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} \Omega_Y. $$
We want to extend $\nabla'$ to $f^* E$; i.e. we want to check that $$ (f^*\nabla)(e\otimes y) = \nabla'(e)\cdot y + (e\otimes 1)\otimes dy, \quad y\in\mathcal{O}_Y, ', e\in f^{-1} E$$ gives a well-defined map $f^* E\to f^* E \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} \Omega_Y$. This amounts to checking that
$$ \nabla'(e)\cdot xy + (e\otimes 1)\otimes dxy = \nabla'(ex)y + (ex\otimes 1)\otimes dy, \quad x\in f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X,\, y\in \mathcal{O}_Y,\, e\in f^{-1} E. $$
For this, use the fact that the Leibniz rule for $E$ implies $\nabla'(ex) = e\otimes dx + \nabla'(e)\cdot x$.

One also needs to check that $f^*\nabla$ satisfies the Leibniz rule.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: Great answer! Do you happen to know of a textbook that covers this? It's tough to find this stuff written up in sheafy language

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to proceed as follows : show that there exists a unique connection $f^*\nabla$ on $f^*\mathcal F$ verifying :

$$ (f^*\nabla)(f^*s) = f^*(\nabla(s))$$

where on the right-hand side  you use the canonical morphism $f^* (\mathcal F\otimes \Omega^1_X)\to  f^* \mathcal F\otimes \Omega^1_Y$.

The uniqueness follows from Leibniz rule, as the $f^*s$ generate $f^* \mathcal F$ (locally).

To show the existence locally, you can trivialize $\mathcal F$. Connections on the trivial bundle are of the form $d+\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is a matrix of $1$-forms. It is enough to take the matrix obtained by pulling back each form individually.

Finally, the uniqueness ensures that you can glue these local connections together to get a global solution.